# Passing img to textarea

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make smileys work, so I'm going to post the full problem, maybe someone knows a better solution. I have this chat system, where you can click on a smiley and it's value gets passed to the `<textarea>` much like Google hangouts. Value is "smile_n" where 20 > n > 0. I store it like that in the database, and I have PHP code that's in charge of displaying the proper `<img src="smile_n">` tag when parsing data from SQL, but when I pick a smiley, it will write "smile_n" in the `<textarea>`. Is there ways to change this?

Here's how I drop smileys into the `<textarea>` element:

```
$(".smilepick").click(function(){
 $('#chatty').val($('#chatty').val()+(' ')+$(this).attr('href')+(' '));
  var el = $("#chatty").get(0);
  var elemLen = el.value.length;
  el.selectionStart = elemLen;
  el.selectionEnd = elemLen;
  el.focus();
});
```

Can I somehow make it parse "smile_n" words into images, but keep the value that gets inserted into database "smile_n" so PHP code won't fail?

Comment: image in a **TEXTAREA**? You might wanna use contenteditable `<div>`   instead to get this done.

Comment: Yeah well I wasn't sure if I could somehow overlay "smile_n" with jq (load the image) and hide the "smile_n" from the string.. If I'm supposed to use the `<div>` element, how would I do positioning? So I can have "Something something `<img ...>` something something" exactly where the user added the smiley

Comment: If you're going to go this route, why not just provide a WYSIWYG text editor instead of textarea?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438043/need-a-simple-wysiwyg-editor-with-image-upload

Comment: @DigitalChris never hit me, since smileys are really the only thing there is to it, otherwise it's just a regular `textarea`. I'd try to make it happen somehow without having the editor, otherwise, I'll look into that one, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use div with contenteditable, you could start with something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
Everything contained within this div is editable in browsers that support.
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
var smile_ha_img = '<img src="http://placehold.it/16x16"/>';

$('#editable').keyup(function() {
    $(this).html(function(i, v) {
        return v.replace('smile-ha', smile_ha_img);   
    });
});
```

It will replace every smile-ha with the given image.

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/tb8vQ/1/  Type smile-ha into paragraph on 4th panel.

Then you can make the content of the div be copied to a hidden textarea to be send by your form as usual.

**To Do**

- You must optmize it for the amount of smiles to check and replace.
- After the function replace the string with the html, the carret position is placed on beginning of string (at least in my browser). There are a lot of answers here in Stackoverflow about how to solve this.
- The keyup trigger used here would not be useful for your system if users doesn't type the smile code themselves. But you can change your function to be executed right after the user chose the emoticon.

**Another approach**
There are some WYSIWYG editors that allow you to choose which features you want to offer to your users. So maybe you could find one that you could hide all options but emoticons.

Comment: Heya, that's pretty awesome man, thank you. To avoid the keyup, I'll simply execute this right after I add "smile-ha" with the onclick! As for number, there's maybe 20 and I'm thinking of doing `foreach` loop. It won't be heavy, since it happens only when user actually chooses the smiley, so it's all good.

Just one more question, using this method, what would `$_POST` value of the div be? Would it be `<img src="smile-ha">` or would it be "smile-ha"?

Comment: It will post `<img src="smile-ha">`. So you will have 3 basic approachs:
1) Let it save it like this (you'll probably need to strip html, slashes and quotes). This way you won't need the function on frontend.

Comment: **If you want to save as `smile-ha`:** 2) You convert `<img src="smile-ha">` again to simple `smile-ha` before save. 3) You can use the WYSIWYG concept. You keep the textarea where user input the text and you copy the content to a div (not editable) where it will show the final result. Check third way: http://jsfiddle.net/tb8vQ/2/

Comment: yeah third is nice, but for what I'm using it, second option is the best. I'll combine the code I have with what you told me and get the result. If I release it (for free) someplace, I'll make sure to credit you for it. Thanks a lot, appreciate the time you took to help me out :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you some way. I hope you could launch your project soon! And sorry my english if I was confusing.

Comment: so do I! I'd love to make it free and open source. English is awesome, no worries :)